# How to print the date in dd/mm format in java

Tags: java, datetime-format

I want to write a class so that I can print the date in `dd/mm` format, but I have no idea to start.

Here is the `main()` part

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortMonthDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonthDate[] mdates = new MonthDate[5];
        mdates[0] = new MonthDate(22, 7);
        mdates[1] = new MonthDate(25, 8);
        mdates[2] = new MonthDate(25, 6);
        mdates[3] = new MonthDate(28, 9);
        mdates[4] = new MonthDate(5, 9);
        print(mdates);
        Arrays.sort(mdates);
        print(mdates);
    }

    static <T> void print(T[] a) {
        for (T t : a) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", t);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement the `toString` method in your `MonthDate` class.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're building a custom class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In this place we’re poor at questions in the style of *I have no idea to start*, sorry. You’ve got to read the tutorials (search and you will find) about how to create a class and how to control how it prints (search for `toString`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 3):

There's a class for that!

## `java.time.MonthDay`

Rather than roll-your-own, use the `MonthDay` class built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port.

```
MonthDay[] mds = new MonthDay[5] ;
mds[0] = MonthDay.of( 7 , 22 ) ;
mds[1] = MonthDay.of( Month.AUGUST , 25 ) ;
mds[2] = MonthDay.of( Month.JUNE , 25 ) ;
mds[3] = MonthDay.of( Month.SEPTEMBER , 28 );
mds[4] = MonthDay.of( 9 , 5 ) ;
Arrays.sort(mdates);
```

Better to use [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) generally.

```
List< MonthDay > mds = new ArrayList<>() ;
mds.add( MonthDay.of( 7 , 22 ) ) ;
mds.add( MonthDay.of( Month.AUGUST , 25 ) ) ;
mds.add( MonthDay.of( Month.JUNE , 25 ) ) ;
mds.add( MonthDay.of( Month.SEPTEMBER , 28 ) ) ;
mds.add( MonthDay.of( 9 , 5 ) ) ;
Collections.sort( mds ) ;
```

## Strings

> I want to write a class so that I can print the date in dd/mm format,

To learn about writing the class, check out [the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/MonthDay.java) in the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

As for generating text representing that month-day class, simply call `toString` to generate a value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I strongly suggest use these standard formats for logging, storing, and exchanging date-time values as text.

```
MonthDay.of( Month.JUNE , 25 ) )
        .toString()
```

> --06-25

For presentation to the user, specify your desired format with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Search Stack Overflow for more info, as this has been covered many many times already.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" ) ;
String output = mds.get( 0 ).format( f ) ;  // Generate string in custom format.
```

> 25/06

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "mds: " + mds ) ;
System.out.println( "mds.get( 0 ) = " +  mds.get( 0 ) + "  |  output: " + output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oBacf9).

> mds: [--06-25, --07-22, --08-25, --09-05, --09-28]
>
> mds.get( 0 ) = --06-25  |  output: 25/06

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing an Object to `System.out` Java uses the [Object.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method to get a string representation of your Object. So you can overwrite the default `toString()` method by implementing it in your `MonthDate` class.

To format the int values you can use the [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method. The format `%02d` pads the value with a `0` if smaller than 10. To get the `dd/mm` format you can use `%02d/%02d`.

With that said your `toString()` method can look like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%02d/%02d", this.day, this.month);
}
```

Using `new MonthDate(12, 3)` this would print:

```
12/03
```

Instead of:

```
MonthDate@42af3438
```

Comment: Thanks in advance! I still quite confuse, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @陈俊杰 every class in java is a child of Object, which has the method toString(). That's why System.out.printf calls toString for any Object it recieves. But the default implementation of toString for a new Class just prints the class name and a hash for the object which isn't very helpful, so you have to override the default implementation to make it print what you want, just like Samuel Philipp did

Comment: @陈俊杰 I edited my answer and added an explanation to the `String.format()` method, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `MonthDate` class attributes are

```
private int day;
private int month;
```

You should always implement a `toString()` method for every class in java because you will be representing every object differently.

As for sorting your objects by date, you cannot use `Arrays.sort()` because you're not sorting numbers. You should implement your own sorting method.Here's one i recommend you:

```
public static void sort(MonthDate[] s) {
    int[] days = new int[s.length];
    int[] months = new int[s.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        days[i] = s[i].day;
        months[i] = s[i].month;
    }

    Arrays.sort(days);
    Arrays.sort(months);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i].day = days[i];
        s[i].month = months[i];
    }
}
```

We put the `days` and `months` in 2 different arrays and sorted them using `Arrays.sort()`, then assigned them back to the object instance.

You can also implement this `toString()` method and then call it in your `print()` method, because you cannot print an object directly with `System.out.println()`.

```
public String toString() {
    return "" + this.day + "/" + this.month;
}
```

In your `print()` function you should use the `toString()` method as so:

```
public static <T> void print(T[] a) {
    for (T t : a) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Finally, you can keep your `main` like that and it would sort it and print it correcty.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MonthDate[] mdates = new MonthDate[5];
    mdates[0] = new SortMonthDate(22, 7);
    mdates[1] = new SortMonthDate(25, 8);
    mdates[2] = new SortMonthDate(25, 6);
    mdates[3] = new SortMonthDate(28, 9);
    mdates[4] = new SortMonthDate(5, 9);
    print(mdates);
    sort(mdates);
    print(mdates);
}
```

Here's the full code:

**MonthDate class**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MonthDate {

    private int day;
    private int month;

    public MonthDate(int day, int month) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
    }

    public static void sort(MonthDate[] s) {
        int[] days = new int[s.length];
        int[] months = new int[s.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            days[i] = s[i].day;
            months[i] = s[i].month;
        }

        Arrays.sort(days);
        Arrays.sort(months);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            s[i].day = days[i];
            s[i].month = months[i];
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + this.day + "/" + this.month;
    }

    public static <T> void print(T[] a) {
        for (T t : a) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**SortMonthDate class**

```
public class SortMonthDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            MonthDate[] mdates = new MonthDate[5];
            mdates[0] = new MonthDate(22, 7);
            mdates[1] = new MonthDate(25, 8);
            mdates[2] = new MonthDate(25, 6);
            mdates[3] = new MonthDate(28, 9);
            mdates[4] = new MonthDate(5, 9);
            MonthDate.print(mdates);
            MonthDate.sort(mdates);
            MonthDate.print(mdates);

    }

}
```

Note that instead of making your `MonthDate` methods static, you could make them not static and call them in `main` using, for example, `mdates.print();`.

Comment: “In your print() function you should use the toString() method” —Actually, `System.out.println(t)` is sufficient.  toString() will be invoked automatically.

Comment: Those numbers are underlying and the complier said cannot applied to int, int. What is the problem?       mdates[0] = new SortMonthDate(22, 7);
        mdates[1] = new SortMonthDate(25, 8);
        mdates[2] = new SortMonthDate(25, 6);
        mdates[3] = new SortMonthDate(28, 9);
        mdates[4] = new SortMonthDate(5, 9);

Comment: @陈俊杰 at what line is the error? Can you put it here as it is?

Comment: in the main part, mdates[0] = new SortMonthDate(22, 7);
    mdates[1] = new SortMonthDate(25, 8);
    mdates[2] = new SortMonthDate(25, 6);
    mdates[3] = new SortMonthDate(28, 9);
    mdates[4] = new SortMonthDate(5, 9);

Comment: I can't help you if you don't copy paste the error as it is.

Comment: @陈俊杰 make sure the day and month attributes in your MonthDate class are of type int not double or anything.

Comment: So in the class MonthDate, I should only write this:                                  private int day;                                                                                         private int month;                                                                                    public String toString() {
    return "" + this.day + "/" + this.month;
}

Comment: @陈俊杰 I added the full code to my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It does not work. There is a warning message: "The constructor MonthDate(int, int) is undefined". But int the MonDate class, it has already declare the filed.